Were the air traffic controller’s actions intentional?
In Breaking Bad season 2's ending, Jane’s father, Donald, returns to work as an air traffic controller. 
In the Breaking Bad wiki, it states that he’s distracted by Jane’s death. 
However, every time I see that scene, he’s sweating, and I’m thinking he’s intentionally putting two planes at the same altitude on headings that would be both hard to see each other and relatively easy to crash into each other. 
Bearing in mind, air traffic is wildly open, a 3D space, instead of 2D like cars on a road. However, he precisely aligns two planes on the same 2D plane, which vastly enhances the possibility of collision.
Was this intentional or just distracted work, as the wiki said?



In this scene, he clearly sees two planes on a heading that, if given the same altitude, would collide. He specifically tells them to get to the same altitude. On his screen, literally right in front of him, he sees the radius circles turn red, and he does nothing to prevent it. This is why I believe he intentionally set both of these planes to collide, not by accident. 
The episode description (don’t know if this is official or not) says “Jane’s grief stricken father takes action that results in further tragedy”, which enhances my assertion even more. 
What’s interesting is that we basically never know anything about Jane’s father afterwards, e.g. the investigation, any incarceration, or similar. 
At the end of S4E4, after Shrader turns down the El Paso assignment, we see Walt driving, who hears a news report about Donald being taken to a hospital for a self-inflicted gunshot wound. 

Why do you assume the wiki is incorrect?

"He is grief-stricken after her death, and his mental agonies cause him to be distracted enough to accidentally let two planes collide. He is advised by a colleague to take the day off, but disregards it. Watch his face during the moment before the collision. His expression clearly shows that he is distracted and his mind is on his dead daughter, not his work. The fact that we hear on the news later that Donald shot himself suggests that he felt overwhelming guilt at what he did."

There’s plenty in the show to suggest it’s an accident caused by him being distracted. Is there anything you see in the show that suggests it’s intentional? In other words, why do you think it might be intentional?

Intentional just because he’s sweating profusely, like he knows what he’s about to do is not good, but he’s not in a good mind state.  The closeups of the sweating brow is what really makes me think that he’s doing it knowing it’ll be bad.

@BCdotWEB you could be right, but his initial motivation could still be intentional.  It’s just the camera angles and closeup showing the sweating of his brow that really makes me think the writers had something else planned on that plot line.

@enorl76 what you said in your query seems to be correct and it seems like they are planning something new to show regarding the same incident in the next episodes/series. So wait and watch. I have found that when a close camera angle is taken in movies or series they have some impact or story within itself going further.

Ok I see that you interpret the sweating as indicating intention. I’ve never had that association myself. Seems to me the sweating is because he’s overwhelmed and in distress.

"specifically tells them to get to the same altitude" what makes you think that? I know nothing about air traffic control but I watched the video a few times and nothing obvious about what he said indicated to me that he specifically told them to match their altitude. The most likely scenario is that due to his distraction he mistakenly provided an instruction to one airplane that was intended for the other one.

@shim I thought i heard him put WAF515 and JM021 at the same altitude.  By the transcript, the only planes at a declared same altitude are JM021 and LFG46 which is leaving ABQ.  Seems like the only thing that caused the accident was WAF515 ordered to descend to 10000, right through JM21's heading 115 and altitude of 13000.  So it seems more unintended.  One could still argue this being intentional with any kind of knowledge of vector math.  Only thing to stop accident is WAF515 pilot seeing JM21 below him but we've all seen commercial airline pilot windows right?  Not much down visibility.

Yea I couldn't really parse the air controller lingo at all. But they obviously don't expect viewers to understand what he's saying, and the point is it is just a lot of technical jargon and his mistake is undecipherable to the average listener. Also pilots have more than just their eyes don't they? What about TCAS? Relevant Reddit thread I found seems to confirm that the scenario in the show is pretty unlikely.

Also TIL there was a real crash that some claim inspired the one in the show (possibly just a crazy coincidence), and there was an air traffic controller "Walter R. White" involved.
